# Does changing a website's platform affect its SEO?

Tags: seo, cms, migration

I want to change my website platform from WordPress to Laravel 5 with new design. If I keep the URLs same as WordPress site, will it affect my current SEO?

Note: I will keep all the pages URL the same.

Comment: You don't say if you are keeping the same content

Comment: content will remain same.
Actually be specific i'm more conscious about that if i change framework the whole project structure will change.
Will this effect to my current SEO.

Comment: What I would suggest before changing things 100% is to run everything new on another server of the same hardware specs and location with new URLs and test things on the old and new server using webpagetest.org. I say this because Laravel might have extra code in their scripts that causes slowdowns where as Wordpress wouldn't cause such slowdowns. Measure the time-to-first byte of each page just to make sure.

Answer (score 5):

Any used framework under the hood has no effect on the SEO. What it matters SEO wise is the front-end (on Site SEO), and the off-site SEO.

Generally any structural, mark-up, content changes have their own effect on SEO. Such changes can be done even with no underlying technology change.

For sure changing framework can't affect off-Site SEO.
For on-site, if after changing your framework you end-up with the exact same mark-up, content, meta and micro data, URLs, speed and anything else that constitute your current site from the SEO perspective, then there will be no effect.

If you have decided to change the framework, this should be a decision based on your project requirements to meet new needs, that another framework can't offer.

You could use this chance to improve your on-site SEO as well. So you may want to plan early and thoroughly, in order to end up with a more robust and solid website, that will bring in new features, functionality and be more optimized for search engines and users alike.

Answer (score 2):

**Can you answer all these questions with "yes":**

- Is the html the same after the change?
- Is the content the same after the change?
- Is the site's speed the same after the change?
- Are the sent headers the same after the change?
- Is the new version indistinguishable for bots?

If you can answer these with yes, then no changes will occur. Otherwise there will be changes. These changes might be for the better (e.g. if the new CMS is faster), of not (e.g. it's slower than before).

The question you have to ask yourself is: Is the new CMS better or worse from a SEO point of few, that answer answers your question.

Comment: no i have changed my design.

Comment: A CMS change and a site redesign can be done without negatively effecting SEO.   Done wrong, it can be a disaster.     It is best to make one change at a time when possible so that you can roll back something that clearly didn't work well.  Martijn's list is everything you need to pay attention to.