# Will changing the theme of a new WordPress website affect SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, theme

I created a new WordPress website and while I was updating a theme there will always be some issues in all the themes I used I am not good at coding and all, I just wanted to know that will change the theme of my website will affect the SEO of the site or not?

Comment: If you aren't good at coding, I would recommend rebuilding your site with a page builder theme such as Divi or Elementor. It will make your life way easier. They _do_ cost some money but if you ever run into issues you'll have customer support to help you.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the main question: does your website already have organic traffic from search engines? If not, you shouldn't worry about SEO with changing the WordPress theme. If yes, read below.

If you don't know at least a little about SEO, it will be difficult for you to make this move safely. You need to analyze the changes that will occur after moving to a new WordPress theme. Of course, the most important thing is that you do not change the URL and content of the pages. In addition, the important questions are:

- Will the structure of the pages change? I mean, the `html5` structure of pages (`h1-h6`, `section`, `article`, `aside`, etc).
- Will the pages metadata change? Use [metatags.io](https://metatags.io/) for checking.
- Will the structure data of pages change? Use [validator.schema.org](https://validator.schema.org/) for checking.
- Is the new design no worse than the old one for users? Analyze convenience of theme.
- The new WordPress theme doesn't have big scripts that make the pages load longer? Find out how new the topic is SEO-friendly. You can use [web.dev](https://web.dev/measure/) or [pagespeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) for the base checking.

It is better for your site to be checked by a SEO specialist. I might have missed some possible problems. To find out everything, need to look at WordPress themes.

I recommend you think, probably easier to fix the current Wordpress theme and hire a developer.

And don't forget about backups.

Comment: They say it is a new website.   I'm not sure that changes are all that relevant in this case compared to making sure that whatever theme you choose does a good job.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller if his website is absolutely new and doesn't have any organic traffic, he can doesn't think about this changes with Wordpress theme. I will add this to my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is similar to [changing website's platform](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95931/does-changing-a-websites-platform-affect-its-seo?rq=1)

So if the structural, mark-up, meta, micro data and content remain the same, it doesn't affect SEO.

For WordPress, the theme is one of the most important factors in SEO. You should use a theme that is SEO friendly which has good structural, meta,  and micro data. And don't change the themes if you don't have a good reason, because mostly WordPress theme has different structural especially if the creator is different.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that switching from a theme that implements good SEO practices to another theme that does the same would affect SEO.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes I agree, only if you know that theme has good SEO practices, but I found many themes that say they have good SEO but are actually bad or outdated.